# Validation only in specific form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Is there any way to trigger validation only in specific forms(controller's action), not globally at every save or update?
Something like `User.create(:validate=>true)` flag.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Maybe we can give a better answer if we know the reasons behind your question.

Comment: I've got messed User model, not separated from profile, when you register you need to provide only few fields and rest is to fill in from edit user action.

Comment: Btw you can pass all validations like that: Model.save(false)

Comment: I'd just point out that this sounds like a bad idea. Validations are there to protect your database from data that makes no sense.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to rebuild half of application... some basic validations are mantadory.

Comment: What you *should* be doing is validating them if they are present. Or perhaps using a wizard-style form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can supply conditionals to the validations, eg:

```
validates_presence_of :something, :if => :special?

private

def make_sepcial
  @special = true
end

def special?
  @special
end
```

Now all you have to do to turn on these validations is:

```
s = SomeModel.new
s.make_special
```

Comment: Nope. `@special` is just an instance variable. Unless you have further work to do then you can just let it die, it won't be persisted to further database queries.

Answer (score 4):

As you explained in the comments, you want to skip validation for new records. In that case, you can use thomasfedb's answer, but don't use the `@special` variable, but:

```
validates_presence_of :something, :if => :persisted?
```

This will validate only for saved `User`s, but not for new `User`s. See the API documentation on [`persisted?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F).

Comment: You can also use :unless => :persisted? if you want the reverse - validation on new but not for saved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old. But I found http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options to be a good way of handling this sort of behaviour.