# rails validate depending on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two separate forms for a profile picture and the rest of the profile information.  Both forms, however, correspond to the profile model.  For several of the profile attributes, I have validations like:

```
validates :title, presence: true
validates :zip_code, presence: true
```

The problem is that the validations are checked when someone tried to upload an image, which I don't want.  That being said, I also have an image validator, so I don't want to avoid validation completely, just certain ones.  I was thinking of trying to access the params hash in the model, but I can't figure out how and I'm pretty certain its a bad idea anyway.  How can I make the right validation conditions?  I already tried this:

```
validates :title, presence: true, :unless => :picture_exists?

def picture_exists?
    if self.pic
        puts 'yo pic exist'
        return true
    else
        puts 'yo no pic'
        return false
    end
end
```

but it does not work because it checks whether or not the profile has a picture, not whether the params have a picture.  So if someone had already saved a picture, they would be able to bypass the validations which I don't want.  I want the validations to be bypassed when they are not using the picture submit form.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the issue in several ways:

1.- Skip all validations in your controller action (and validate manually, I guess)

`save(validate: false)` ([source](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations))

2.- Use a condition that you set manually before saving [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545850/validation-only-in-specific-form).

3.- Use a custom validation that stops all other validations from triggering if passes.

Maybe you can come up with more.

PS: Why would you expect your user to bypass the other validations before setting the profile picture?

GL & HF

Comment: Thanks, number 3 could work, but is there a way to actually do that?  I'm not sure I understand your PS question?

Comment: I think number 2 is better (and closely related to 3). Maybe this can shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881712/skip-certain-validation-method-in-model

Comment: @Philip7899 About the PS I ask why would all the other validations trigger errors? Does your app flow considers the use case of setting a profile picture even with other fields empty (or whatever you're validating)?

Comment: the stack overflow question you posted looks like what i need.  The only problem is i can't do "new_car=Car.new(skip_method_2: true)" because i already do @profile = Profile.new(profile_params) , So how can i pass "skip_method: true"?

Comment: @Philip7899 you can append all the keys you want to a hash. I'm not quite sure but `profile_params[:skip_method] = true` should do the trick. Check out ruby hash docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html